# Conversion from Log4j.xml to Log4j2.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, log4j2

Dear Stackoverflow people I need your help.

I am currently sitting on a project that has log4j logging and I want to upgrade it to log4j2. Reason behind this is I want to implement spring profiles and refer logging files to the compatible environment logging configurations.

My problem is that I moved the log4j.xml file out of my Resource folder, and inserted my log4j2.xml instead. However the application is still looking for log4j.xml. Getting following message using Log4j.debug in command line.

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

So apparently my application still think i'm trying to use regular log4j.

I have updated my dependency from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And I have removed all other sorts of log4j logging in my pom.xml file. I have furthermore excluded logback from spring-boot-starter dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

All help is appreciated. If I have a referenced .jar my own project that uses log4j, could this perhaps conflict or would I get a visible error?

Comment: Have you look for the "log4j.xml" string in your code? It could help you find where the Log4J config file is set up.

Comment: Could you please make sure that there is no log4j.jar in the classpath? In maven you can run "maven dependency:tree" and analyze the output, another way is to open up spring boot jar/war built by spring boot plugin with some viewer (WinRar, winzip, etc.) and check the content of the lib folder (WEB-INF/lib for WAR and BOOT-INF/lib for jar)

Comment: First do what @MarkBramnik said.  Also, remember that order is important with the dependency tree.  So you could try putting the spring-boot-starter-log4j2 at the top of your dependencies section.

Comment: It is so that I have a referenced project which is using log4j, log4j-api, log4j-core and log4j-slf4j-impl, and I can see these jars in my BOOT-INF\lib\ folder.

Is it possible that this is my problem? Is it so that you cannot implement log4j2 if a subproject is using log4j one?